# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1 and many times at Gradle building it gives me below message.

Can anybody help me with it! I think there some memory issue in Android Studio.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> value (119282) > 0x0000ffff
```

And after restart, it works perfect. It's strange because in previous version 1.5.0 this issue has never occur to me.

Comment: Any one please help me with this, I have increased below params of studio.exe.vmoption.  '-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m '. But still facing the same issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved by changing gradle version from "gradle:2.2.0-alpha1" to newly arrived version "gradle:2.1.2" which was released in this month. Also I have not changed Android Studio.

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1. I think it's due to alpha version of gradle.

May be this would help to others also.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in latest android Studio Build, 
For Windows, Kill "OpenJDK Plateform Binary" Task from task Manager and It'll disappear for some next Build. Currently, There is no permanaent solution of this issue.

Comment: Yes.. It also depends on phone memory. As scenario I have, while debugging in low RAM device this happens many times.